# How to remove a system app from the Play Store updates list

Tags: google-play-store, updates, system-apps

I wonder how I can remove *SwiftKey Keyboard* form the updates list.

[image]

### Notes

- It's a system app.
- Its <kbd>Disable</kbd> button is grayed out.

Comment: Disable automatic update in Google Play settings, the apps won't automatically update

Comment: @esQmo_: Then I'll have to manually get updates for each app separately, right?

Comment: Indeed. That's the only way as far as I know